# How can I clear the table before importing the CSV using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, import-from-csv

I'm not the most skilled developer however my friends and I grouped up for a project and have created a plant automated watering system. My responsibility is getting the website to work and display the statistics the system creates.

**How can I have my code clear the table before adding the new data from the CSV file?**

Here's the code displayed on the index page:

```
<!-- Importing the CSV -->

        <div id="wrap">
        <h2 class='sub-header'>Upload .csv to refresh data</h2>
          <?php
            include("csv.php");
            $csv = new csv();
            if ( isset($_POST['sub'])) {
              $csv->import($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            }
          ?>

          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-info"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Import" class="btn btn-success"> 
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the PHP file:

```
<?php
class csv extends mysqli
{
    private $state_csv = false;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("localhost","root","raspberry","statistics");
        if ($this->connect_error) {
            echo "Failed to connect to the database: ". $this->connect_error;
        }
    }
    public function import($file)
    {
        $file = fopen($file, 'r');
        while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
            $value = "'". implode("','", $row) ."'";
            $q = "INSERT INTO data(moisture_of_soil,temperature,humidity,light_levels,last_updated) VALUES(". $value .")";
            if ( $this->query($q) ) {
                $this->state_csv = true;
            }else {
                $this->state_csv = false;
            }
        }
        if ($this->state_csv) {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        } else {
            echo "Something went wrong.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE tablename` or `DELETE FROM tablename`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Remember MySQL can read CSV files directly using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. There's no need to intermediate if you're loading local data.

Answer (score 2):

`TRUNCATE name` is very quick and efficient, but will reset all `AUTO_INCREMENT` values. If you have other tables which reference this table through those sorts of identifiers this could be problematic, it could link data to random places.

`DELETE FROM name` will delete everything but won't reset `AUTO_INCREMENT` counters. It tends to be slower, especially on large tables with a lot of contention, but has the advantage of not recycling identifiers.

You'll need to determine which of the two is appropriate for your particular use case. For a table that's not cross-linked referentially, `TRUNCATE` usually works best.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down to me. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this way:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;   (or spell out the schema)
LOAD DATA .. INTO new ...;
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

The only slow part is the `LOAD`.
The RENAME is atomic.
The table `real` is always available (no downtime).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an addendum to @tadman's already-correct answer, but too long-form for a comment.

The performance difference is that `TRUNCATE` more or less just drops the table's data file and makes a new empty one, which is one big, fairly contiguous IO operation that your OS can handle quite efficiently.

On the other hand a series of `DELETE` statements is a lot of tiny IO operations that will bog down your disk, and also not recover any space in the backing data files.

If you *have* to go the `DELETE` route I highly recommend enclosing all of the deletes inside of a transaction which will help optimize the IO to some degree. Then, once you've got all of the data imported [which should also be in a transaction, preferably even the same one] you can run an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` operation to recover any unused disk space from the backing data files, assuming there's a significant enough difference in data size to warrant it.

Third option:

1. Add a field that is basically `last_updated`.
2. `START TRANSACTION;`
3. `SET @start = NOW();`
4. Loop: `INSERT INTO table ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;`
5. `DELETE FROM table WHERE last_updated < @start;`
6. `COMMIT;`

As a bonus, if you're using transactions like this there's no point in time when your application would have a "bad" or missing set of data.

Refs:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks for providing that third option. Going to test it out and see how it plays out. Cheers!